# How to reuse mysql CRUD in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, crud

I have an idea, but I don't know how to implement it. Let's say there are various tables in our db and each table may have different fields. I need to create a parent class which has some common database functions for CRUD (create, read, update and delete). (It might take the table name as an argument). We can re-use all these CRUD methods in our sub-classes. We don't have to specify field names.

```
class AllCRUD{

  protected function select (){
   // select * from ..... comes here

  }

  protected function create (){
   // select * from ..... comes here

  }

  // update and delete comes then


} 

class Users extends ALLCRUD{
    protected $table_name="users";

    //Mechanism to iterate through field names

}

//create the object
$user=new Users();
$user->select() 
//This will select all users from users table
//Likewise we must be able to perform insert, update and delete on any subclass
```

I believe you guys may have understood what I am trying to say
I need someone's help to implement this concept.
If there is a blog or something that I can read, please post the link.
(I searched, but did not find something which fits for my purpose)

Thanks

Comment: Just a side note: why not using the ready-to-go ORM, like Doctrine or Propel? They implement all CRUD operations and do much more.

Comment: please read http://stackoverflow.com/about

Comment: You might also want to read about (generic) DAO [Data Access Objects]. Apart from that, implementing what you want to achieve is dependant on a way you access the database.

Comment: @Ruslan - What is this ORM?

Comment: [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) (Object-relational mapping) in short is a tool that solves exactly the problem you have. What you are doing now is creating another one.

Answer (score 2):

Recently I was doing exactly the [same problem](https://github.com/barif/Meeting/blob/master/Meetingroom/Model/AbstractCRUDModel.php)

And extended child [EventModel](https://github.com/barif/Meeting/blob/master/Meetingroom/Model/Event/EventModel.php)

In my example, Event Model inheritance AbstractCRUDModel and implement this logic.
For example:

```
//create model object
$eventModel = new EventModel();
// fetching from database
$event = $eventModel->read(1);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can refer to a very early version of a lightweight simple ORM framework with just few files and easy to use and understand.

PHP Tiny Framework:
https://github.com/sushilman/ptf

It does not provide enough security by itself (like: against SQL injection ) which you will have to take care of by yourself.

If your project is large enough and if you want other features of a framework, then I would recommend you to use one of several available PHP frameworks : Zend, CodeIgniter, Symphony and so on.